# PowerPoint: memorize "hide slide" patterns

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Is there a way to [hide](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/hide-or-show-a-slide-8313e1ec-3e20-4464-952f-387931554d69) a specific fixed set of PowerPoint slides easily, so I don't have to select that entire set every time I want to hide them? It should be based on the content of exactly these slides, not on their numbers. (Because numbers change when other slides get inserted/deleted.)

Maybe a new PowerPoint version can assign tags/categories to slides, and a built-in PowerPoint feature can hide slides with that tag? Or a tag can be added to the [speaker notes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-speaker-notes-to-your-slides-26985155-35f5-45ba-812b-e1bd3c48928e) - can a macro then read it and hide the respective slides, how?

*Backstory: I have a set of PowerPoint slides which I continuously keep updating and from which I give talks to slightly different target audiences on partially overlapping topics. Sometimes I hide slides number, say, 3,7,15,20,25,30. On another day I unhide them but hide slides 2,4,10,17. Then I improve slides 11,12,14. Then I unhide all but hide slides 3,7,15,20,25,30 again.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this with text on the notes pages. Something like

`~!hidden`

(because ~! is a pattern that just won't appear in any text I'm ever likely to use)

Then go to Slide Sorter view, find all occurrences of `~!hidden` , and click the "hide slide" button. Done.

I use similar things to identify subsets of slides for other purposes.

Of course if you want the notes pages to contain notes that get printed with your handout you're going to have to think a little harder. It's pretty easy to put all of these "tags" at the end of a notes page, where most readers will ignore them. If they really bother you on the printed notes pages you can write a little VBAscript to get rid of them.

Comment: You could do something similar by adding a "flag" shape off the slide so it'd be visible while you're editing the show but not when presenting/printing, and you wouldn't have to worry about whether it prints on notes pages. The disadvantage of this or your method is that it only works to show/hide one subset of slides, whereas the tagging suggestion above allows any slide or slides to be in one, many or all versions of the presentation.

Comment: Regarding "the disadvantage", no - "~!hidden" is not my only possible string. :)

Comment: More precise instructions: *View→Slide Sorter*, then *Home→Find* (or Ctrl+F), search for your codeword like `~!hidden`, click *Find All*, and then *Slide Show→Hide Slide* (or *right click on one of the selected slides → Hide Slide*)

Comment: Alternative if you want to mark which slides should be non-hidden rather than hidden: First hide all slides, then use the same technique to search for the `codeword` and unhide them.

Comment: I appreciate the upvote and "best answer" pick, but I think Steve Rindsberg's VBAscript deserves some love too.

Comment: Ditto back at you, @JamieHanrahan. It's always good to have several possible solutions to chose from, and sometimes a non-VBA solution is the best/most flexible.

Answer (score 2):

@root 
"Maybe a new PowerPoint version can assign tags/categories to slides,"

Any Windows version from '97 onward can assign multiple "tags" to presentations, SLIDES, or shapes on slides. I'm fairly sure that the same is true of Mac PPT versions, other than 2008, which didn't have VBA. There's no user interface for tags; you need to use VBA or other programming languages to work with them.

Once the slide is tagged, it doesn't matter if you move it around within the show; the tag stays with the slide.

Using VBA, for example, for each different show within the presentation, you'd hide all the slides in the show, then run TagSlides:

```
Sub TagSlides()
' NOTE: mark all the slides in this show
' as hidden before running this code

Dim sShowName As String
Dim oSl As Slide

' Get a name for this show/set of slides
' Quit if user enters nothing
sShowName = InputBox("Name of show", "Show name")
If Len(sShowName) = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    ' If it's hidden, tag it with the show name
    If oSl.SlideShowTransition.Hidden Then
        oSl.Tags.Add Ucase(sShowName), "Y"
        ' you could run the same code to set the tag value
        ' to "" if you want to remove the tag
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Having done that, you can run this, which'll ask you for the show name you want to use and then make any slides that belong to that show visible, hide the others.

```
Sub MakeShowVisible()

Dim sShowName As String
Dim oSl As Slide

' Get a name for this show/set of slides
' Quit if user enters nothing
sShowName = InputBox("Name of show", "Show name")
If Len(sShowName) = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    If Len(oSl.Tags(Ucase(sShowName))) > 0 Then
        ' the slide belongs to the show so unhide it
        oSl.SlideShowTransition.Hidden = False
    Else
        ' not part of the show; hide it
        oSl.SlideShowTransition.Hidden = True
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

One slide can belong to multiple shows.
If you need to add new slides to a show, first run HideShow below, which will hide all of the slides currently in a given show, then hide the new slide(s) and run TagSlides again.

```
Sub HideShow()

Dim sShowName As String
Dim oSl As Slide

' Get a name for this show/set of slides
' Quit if user enters nothing
sShowName = InputBox("Name of show", "Show name")
If Len(sShowName) = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    If Len(oSl.Tags(sShowName)) > 0 Then
        ' the slide belongs to the show so hide it
        oSl.SlideShowTransition.Hidden = True
    Else
        ' not part of the show; UNhide it
        oSl.SlideShowTransition.Hidden = False
    End If
Next

End Sub
```